# Explain 1<<16 | 10?

Tags: ruby

I need to use the code below, but I'm new to ruby and programming in general and don't understand what this does.  Can someone tell me what this does or at least what this is called?

```
def MAKELPARAM(w1, w2)
  return (w2<<16) | w1
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: `<<` is the bitshift operator, `|` is a bitwise OR.

Comment: `<<` is left bitwise shift, `|` is bitwise OR. Now you can google :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This performs a left-shift of w2 by 16 bits, then bitwise-or's w1 into the result.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't for the life of me figure out how this worked.  If I inputted MAKELPARAM(10, 1) I would get 65546!  If anyone is interested [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm) is a link to what left-shift, and bitwise-or's is in ruby.

Answer (score 1):

So those could be bitwise operators if you know that they are numbers however if the params coming in are arrays then <<  is the operator to add to the array.  Also then the | operator does an or on the two array's returning an array of the elements that are in either array 
For Example:

```
w1 =[]
w2 = [16,13]
w3 = [13]
MAKELPARAM(w1,w2)
#Returns [16,13]

MAKELPARAM(w1,w3)
#Returns [16,13]

MAKELPARAM(w1,w1)
#Returns [16]
```

Comment: MAKELPARAM(w1,w1)
#Returns [16,16]

Comment: It doesn't because the | or's the two lists together. Give it a go in irb. The | stops there from being duplicates in the outputted list.

Comment: This is the correct answer - the result of the expression depends on classes ```w1``` and ```w2``` are instances of.

Comment: My mistake, I never noticed w3 in your example. However, in irb, for me: MAKELPARAM([2],[2])
=> [2, 16]
because the << 16 inserts 16 into the second parameter, assuming it is an array

Comment: Yup exactly.  The 16 gets appended, then the fact that there are 2 2's gets ignored and the result ends up being [2,16]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it bitshift w2 by 16 places to the left, so i.e. take `w2 = 1`:

```
w2 == 0b1
w2 << 16 == 0b1000000000000000
```

then it use bitewise or with `w1`.